# React-redux batch on React v.18

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, react-18

im using redux toolkit v1.9.0 and react 18.2.0. I have to use dispatch inside forEach. Code example

```
data.forEach(item => {
batch(()=>store.dispatch(createTrack(item)));
})
```

While i was looking [redux documantation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/batch) i saw  an info "If you're using React 18, you do not need to use the batch API. React 18 automatically batches all state updates, no matter where they're queued."

But when i was looking [reduxtoolkit documantation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/autoBatchEnhancer) i saw that there is a batch enchanter.

What should i do delete batch function like

```
   data.forEach(item => {
    store.dispatch(createTrack(item));
    })
```

or change reducer ?

Comment: you can remove the batch function and dispatch actions directly.

Comment: What result did you get? Does it not work after deleting `batch` function?

Comment: yes its working after deleting batch. I didnt observe performance on profiler(chrome).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `batch()` util exported by React-Redux was only necessary with React 17 and earlier.  React 18 automatically batches all queued state updates in a single event loop tick into one re-render.

However, the `autoBatchEnhancer` in RTK does something different.  It cuts down on how many times the Redux store tries to notify subscribers (components) that the store state has been updated, *if* it sees actions marked with a "this action is low-priority" field.  That's separate from React's own batching.

I wrote a post a few years ago comparing several Redux batching techniques:

- https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/01/blogged-answers-redux-batching-techniques/

And the RTK 1.9 release notes discuss the auto batch enhancer:

- https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/releases/tag/v1.9.0

Comment: but my code above is not in react component its in utils.ts
so there is no import React from 'react;

is it still valid

Comment: Yes. That `batch()` function is really a React function called `unstable_batchedUpdates()`.  Any code that executes inside the `batch()` callback is wrapped in React logic that treats all attempted state updates as batchable and queues up re-renders for later, instead of doing them immediately.  It doesn't have anything to do with _writing_ a component or JSX syntax.